$f(p)=S(p\rho +(1-p)\sigma)$, where $S$ is Von Neumann entropy, prove $f''(p)\leq 0$

This exercise is from Quantum Computation and Quantum Information by Nielsen and Chuang. Suppose the concavity holds, then $f(\frac{1}{2})\geq\frac{1}{2}(f(0)+f(1))$, $S(\frac{\rho+\sigma}{2})\geq (S(\rho)+S(\sigma))/2$, by continuity for all $p\in[0,1]$,$S(p\rho+(1-p)\sigma)\geq pS(\rho)+(1-p)S(\sigma)$.
The question is how to prove $f''(p)\leq 0$? Since $\rho$ and $\sigma$ may have different eigenvectors, it is hard to analysis the eigenvalues and Von Neumann entropy of $p\rho +(1-p)\sigma$.

Not a complete solution, but a possible starting point:

Given any positive semidefinite $A\ge0$, the entropy is defined as
$$S(A)=-\operatorname{tr}(A\log A)=-\sum_k \lambda_k(A)\log \lambda_k(A),$$
with the sum extended over the strictly positive eigenvalues $\lambda_k(A)$ of $A$.

Define $A(p)\equiv p\rho +(1-p)\sigma$ for given $\rho,\sigma\ge0$. The linearity of the trace ensures that
$$\partial_p^k \operatorname{tr}(A(p))=\operatorname{tr}(\partial_p^k A(p)).$$
We thus need to compute the derivatives of the parametrised matrix $A(p)$.

Suppose $\rho,\sigma>0$, that is, both matrices are invertible. This ensures that $A(p)$ is also invertible for all $p\in[0,1]$. This allows us to use the identity
$$\operatorname{tr} \partial_p \log A = \operatorname{tr}[A' A^{-1}] = \operatorname{tr}[(\rho-\sigma) A^{-1}(p)].$$
If we had $[A,A']=0$ we could have more directly used
$$\partial_p \log A(p)=A'(p) A^{-1}(p), \qquad A'\equiv \partial_p A,$$
but that's not the case here unless $[\rho,\sigma]=0$ (in which case the problem is trivial anyway). But we can still salvage the identity above thanks to the properties of the trace.
See e.g. this post on math.SE for a thorough discussion of these identities. We thus have
$$\partial_p \operatorname{tr}[A(p) \log A(p)] = \operatorname{tr}[(\rho-\sigma) \log A(p)] + \underbrace{\operatorname{tr}(\rho-\sigma)}_{=0}.$$
Now for the second derivative, we have
$$-f''(p)= \operatorname{tr}[(\rho-\sigma) \partial_p \log A(p)].$$
If we could write $\partial_p \log A(p)=A'(p) A^{-1}(p)$, which holds iff $[A'(p),A^{-1}(p)]=0$, then we'd be done, because we'd have
$$-f''(p) = \operatorname{tr}[(\rho-\sigma)^2 A^{-1}(p)]\ge0,$$
with positivity due to the general fact that $\operatorname{tr}(AB)\ge0$ is $A,B\ge0$.
However, this doesn't hold, except in the trivial case with $[\rho,\sigma]=0$. I'm not sure how to conclude in general. Maybe using the integral representations given in the linked post would work.


